# .desktop file does not work from /usr/share/applications

Tags: ubuntu, software-installation, gnome3, application, .desktop

I created the following `.desktop` file under Fedora 24 using GNOME 3.

```
[Desktop Entry]
Encoding=UTF-8
Name=Jabref
Exec=java -jar /home/zoltan/Bureau/Programs/JabRef-3.7-dev--snapshot--2016-11-08--master--fffad83.jar
Icon=/home/zoltan/Bureau/Programs/Icons/Jabref
Type=Application
Categories=Development
```

When I opened it from the desktop, it launched the application, however when I copied it to `/usr/share/applications`, the system couldn't recognise it and so I cannot launch it quickly. What can be the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look here:
https://developer.gnome.org/integration-guide/stable/desktop-files.html.en

It could be possible gnome to be quite sensitive in the "Categories" section.
You might need to modify like

```
Categories=GTK;GNOME;Development;
```

PS: By the way i just noticed that your "categories" entry is not "closed" with ";" character.

Also, i'm not sure if Development category is present under gnome. You can apply another category (i.e Settings;) to see if it works.

Last chance you could try to modify an existing .desktop file....

Comment: Thanks George, gedit can recognise .desktop files and highlighted the Development category in red. It recognised GTK and GNOME too, so I wrote Categories=GTK;GNOME; (at this time I ended with a semicolon). But still the same. Even after modifying the existing .desktop files.

Comment: Very strange...Maybe you could try alacarte for testing...

Comment: I see all the files in that dir have root ownership. Maybe that's the thing?

Comment: Yes, I also tried alacarte. However, that was buggy on Fedora 24: when I tried to set the path, the OK button remained inactive. I read somewhere that alacarte contains bugs on the latest GNOME 3.

Comment: @tomas Yes, I edited the jabref.desktop with sudo. And I also tried sudo alacarte, but that opened alacarte as a blank app.

Comment: what about putting the file in ~/.local/share/applications? Does it make any difference?

Comment: @GeorgeVasiliou No, it doesn't. I can open it when double-clicking on it, but doesn't integrate to the search menu.

Comment: Gnome documentations says: "Though common in other desktops, creating your own application-specific submenu is not recommended. Instead, provide one menu item for each application you ship. Extra items such as help files, READMEs or links to your web site should be embedded into the application itself. ". Could this mean that something like this is required...? : https://specifications.freedesktop.org/menu-spec/latest/ar01s08.html. I'm in lack of good ideas....

Comment: @GeorgeVasiliou I think the menus are for structuring the applications (see here: https://developer.gnome.org/integration-guide/stable/desktop-files.html.en ) but the .desktop file must be created anyway (see the link).

Comment: @GeorgeVasiliou Very interesting: now works perfectly. I have no idea what the problem was. What I did differently: when I opened it by double-clicking on its icon, I got a prompt if I trust in the application. Originally, I set it as do not ask it again. And then copied from the Desktop to /usr/share/applications. This time, I didn't set it and just copied to /usr/share/applications. Finally it works, but I don't know why. You helped me a lot, so I accept your answer.